# Refreshing Page block table to show recent values from database

Tags: pageblocktable, wrapper-class

Issues faced in code:-
I have a list of Test Person in page block table coming from wrapper.
A detail button on each row shows the details in below section.
When i click on save Details the updated record is saved in database but the pageblock table still shows the old record.
I have rerendered the pageblock table.

How do i refresh the List of wrapper over here

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtTestPerson" value="{!lstTestWrapper}" var="testWrapper">
    <apex:facet name="caption">TEST PERSONS<br />
        <br />
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:column value="{!testWrapper.title}" headerValue="Title"/>
    <apex:column value="{!testWrapper.fName}" headerValue="First Name"/>
    <apex:column value="{!testWrapper.lName}" headerValue="Last Name"/>
    <apex:column value="{!testWrapper.ident}"
        rendered="false" />
    <apex:column >
        <apex:commandButton value="Details" 
            action="{!ViewTestPerson}"
            rerender="pbtTestPerson,pbTestPersonInfo">
            <apex:param name="identity"
                value="{!testWrapper.ident}" assignTo="{!toViewIdent}" />
            <apex:param name="Id" value="{!testWrapper.authId}" assignTo="{!Id}" />
        </apex:commandButton> 
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:outputPanel id="opTestPersonInfo">
    <apex:pageBlock id="pbTestPersonInfo">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsTestPersonInfo"
            title="Test Person">
            <apex:inputField value="{!TestPerson1.Title__c}" label="Title <br/>(Mr,Mrs,etc.)"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!TestPerson1.Surname__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!TestPerson1.First_Name__c}" />
            <apex:inputField value="{!TestPerson1.Local_Language_Name__c}" label="Name in local language "/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:commandButton value="Save Details"
                Action="{!saveTestPerson}"
                rerender="pbtTestPerson,pbTestPersonInfo" />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Class Code

```
public with sharing class TestPersonClass
{       
    public String Id {get;set;}

    public Application__c application{get; set;}
    public Test__c TestPerson1{get;set;}

    public List<TestWrapper> lstTestWrapper {get; set;}

    public Map<Id,Test__c> mapTestPerson{get;set;} 

    public TestPersonClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
    {
        lstTestWrapper=new List<TestWrapper>(); 
        this.application=(Application__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();
        TestPerson1 = new Test__c();

        try
        {
            mapTestPerson = new Map<Id,Test__c>([Select Title__c, Surname__c, Name, Id, First_Name__c,Local_Language_Name__c,Application__c
                                    FROM Test__c
                                    where Application__c = : application.id]);
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }

        for(Test__c authPer:mapTestPerson.values())
        {
            lstTestWrapper.add(new TestWrapper(nextIdent++,authPer));
        }
    }
    public class TestWrapper
    {
        public Integer ident {get; private set;}
        public String fName {get; set;}       
        public String lName {get; set;}
        public String title {get; set;}
        public String authId {get; set;}

        public Test__c ap {get; set;}

        public TestWrapper(Integer inIdent,Test__c test) 
        {         
            ap=test;  
            ident=inIdent;   
            this.fName = test.First_Name__c;
            this.lName = test.Surname__c;
            this.title = test.Title__c;
            this.authId = test.Id;
        }
     }

    public PageReference ViewTestPerson()
    {
        PageReference Pageref= null;

        if (lstTestWrapper != null && lstTestWrapper.size() > 0)
        {
            for(TestWrapper apw : lstTestWrapper)
            {
                if(apw.ident == toViewIdent)
                {
                    this.authorisedPerson1 = apw.ap;
                }
            }
         }

        return Pageref;
    }

    public PageReference saveTestPerson()
    {
        PageReference pageRef = null;
        Id = Id;

        if(mapTestPerson.containsKey(Id))
        {
            TestPerson1.Application__c = this.application.Id;
            update TestPerson1;

            /// How to update the lstwrapper over here... the page block table should be updated...
        }
        else 
        {
            TestPerson1.Application__c = this.application.Id;
            insert TestPerson1;
            lstTestWrapper.add(new TestWrapper(nextIdent++,TestPerson1));
        }

        TestPerson1 = new Test__c();

        return pageRef;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TestWrapper` is taking a copy of the original field values and is not being updated.

Instead I suggest:

```
public class TestWrapper {
    public Integer indent {get; private set;}
    public Test__c sob {get; private set;}       
    public TestWrapper(Integer indent, Test__c sob) {    
        this.indent = indent;       
        this.sob = sob;   
    }
 }
```

and changing the references in the table to e.g.:

```
{!testWrapper.sob.Title__c}
```

Then in your `saveTestPerson` method, update the `Test__c` from the `mapTestPerson` and then when your table refreshes the updated `Test__c` values will be presented.

This approach of using the SObject fields instead of primitive types also ensures that metadata like the field label is available so you will then not need to specify the `headerValue` attributes in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use reRender = "Id of table you want to refresh" in visual force page . I can see you have included rerender that should solve the problem

Comment: YEs i have used it but its not working...

Comment: @TestNS try this  `<apex:pageBlock id="myPageBlock">` and have  `reRender="myPageBlock"`.  If you use reRender, you need to wrap the data you want re-rendered with another `apex` element and then re-render the wrapper-element.  In your case, the `<apex:pageBlock id="myPageBlock">` element strictly contains all the data you want to re-render, so re-render **that** element.